# CSS Select an element based on a neighbour with a specific child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's a simplified structure of a web page.

```html
<div>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2<a href="/foo">foo</a></div>
    <p>select me</p>
    <p>keep me alone</p>
</div>
```

I want to select all `p` based on it's neighbour `div` with `a` inside. Here's my best attempt:

`document.querySelectorAll('(div > a[href="/foo"]) ~ p')`

But obviously this is not a vaild CSS selector.

Is it possible to select `p` if it has a neighbour `div` with `a` inside?

Comment: You could do this using `:has()` - but `:has()` only works inside `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` - it cannot be used in stylesheets. Where are you wanting to use this selector? (As of early 2020, no browser supports `:has()` but there are polyfills for it).

Comment: I want to use the selector in devtools. Is it possible to inject the polyfill in an arbitrary webpage and use `querySelector` with `:has()` polyfilled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to select p if it has a neighbour div with a inside?

You would need to use the `:has()` selector, however the full solution depends if you want to use it in [a "live profile" or a "snapshot profile"](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#profiles):

> The **live profile** is appropriate for use in any context, including browser CSS selector matching, which is live. It includes every selector defined in this document, except for `:has()`:
>
> The **snapshot profile** is appropriate for contexts which aren’t extremely performance sensitive; in particular, it’s appropriate for contexts which evaluate selectors against a static document tree. For example, the `querySelector()` method defined in DOM should use the snapshot profile.

When talking about `:has()` specifically:

- In `.css`/`<style>` stylesheet rule selectors (which is a live context): **No**.
- In `.css`/`<style>` stylesheet rule selectors with client-side scripting to allow the use of `:has()` (which means it actually is used a snapshot context): **Yes**

  - Here's a library to do this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-has-pseudo
- In `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll`, `matches` and other DOM functions (which is a snapshot context): **Yes**

  - But as of May 2020 no browser natively supports using `:has()` in these functions.
  - And after some cursory googling, I couldn't find a polyfill or patch to add support for `:has()` for `querySelector` etc, boo!

But assuming you can use `:has()` (e.g. because you're reading this post in the year 2030), then this query is all you need:

```
div:has(> a[href="/foo"]) ~ p
```

### Why isn't `:has()` in the Live Profile?

There are a variety of reasons why CSS does not support selecting elements based on its children (though there are a limited number of exceptions such as `:empty` and `:focus-within`), but the main reasons are:

- It would make CSS selectors even more computationally expensive to evaluate.
- CSS is designed to work with a partially loaded document, such that as a document is loaded it won't drastically change appearance.

As a thought-experiment: pretending that browsers did support `:has()` in a CSS style rule, consider a HTML document that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background-color: red; }
    p:has(div) { background-color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>foo <div></div></p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>baz <div></div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The "foo" and "baz" elements would be blue, and the "bar" element would be red.

Now if a browser has this document in a partially-loaded state, such that it only has this loaded so far (before the user's Wi-Fi connection died) - or before the next TCP packet arrives:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background-color: red; }
    p:has(div) { background-color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>foo
```

Browsers are required to cleanly terminate a partially-loaded document by inserting their own closing-tags for truncated elements, like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p { background-color: red; }
    p:has(div) { background-color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>foo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So when the document is in this state, the first `p` would be red, not blue - then after the user's Wi-Fi connection reconnects (or the next TCP packet arrives) and the page finishes downloading then `<p>foo</p>` gains the `<div>` and so the `:has(div)` rule now applies and the `<p>foo</p>` **will suddenly change from red to blue** - which isn't good.

Now in this contrived example, a trivial difference like a background-color change doesn't matter all that much - but if the `:has()` selector was used to control some major differences in page layout (e.g. `body:has(footer) > main { display: grid;`) then that would really mess-up the page layout while it's still loading - and this is why selectors based on descendant content will not be supported for now in their current form.

(But given the sheer practicality and utility of parent-of-descendant selectors, I imagine they'll be reintroduced in the future with some way of restricting rules for use only after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired or requiring a default or fallback for when a selector is indeterminate.

Comment: My goal is to query elements on a webpage with devtools. Am I correct that it's not possible with `:has()`, because it's not supported yet? https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I now have a better picture of what is possible and what is not in CSS in 2020. I need to re-think my strategy of querying elements, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, however if you wanted to just select `<p>select me</p>`, why can you not just assign it to a class?

For example,

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2<a href="/foo">foo</a></div>
    <p class="selected">select me</p>
    <p>keep me alone</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have control on the webpage and can't change it's structure and add classes, ids, etc.

Answer (score -1):

As of now (as for as I know) you can't select a parent from a child in CSS, let alone and adjacent "parent".  The best answer I have for you is this though, hopefully it helps.

```css
div + p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2<a href="/foo">foo</a></div>
    <p>select me</p>
    <p>keep me alone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use selectors that use "X contains Y"-type logic, but only inside `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` calls - and not inside stylesheets.

Comment: @Dai yes of course you can do a lot with JS to do that, but I believe it's not possible with only CSS which I think is what the OP was asking.

Comment: Very cool, but still requires JS to perform. Thanks for sharing though.  I didn't know about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the webpage I'm interested in has much more complex structure and `div + p` selector will query elements I'm not interested in. I need to cling to the `a` inside the `div` to get the elements I want.

Comment: I figured as much,  I don't think there is a way to do it in just CSS though unfortunately,  You'll probably need some JS to achieve what you want.